# Source code for SitefInity commuity edition?

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

Telerik have discontinued Sitefinity community edition...they have taken down the download link..anyone have the source code?  Was the source code availble before?  I like the way it worked...

Answer (score 2):

I work for Telerik.

Sitefinity 3.x CE is still available through the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Sitefinity CE is [not being discontinued for 4.0](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/4-0-will-have-a-community-edition.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Gabe.   Was the source code availble for the community edition and if so..can i get it?